# Playing VLC streams directly from web page?

Tags: browser, vlc

I found several pages that provide streams directly (e.g. [JaGledam.com](https://www.jagledam.com)) and in this example, the first two tabs require x-google-vlc-plugin to play the stream.

I can use the link with the Flash player, but I'd prefer to watch them via VLC (either VLC Player for Android or directly from the web page).

Is there any way to watch VLC streams from Android (if relevant, Nexus 5)?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the object (right-click -> Inspect (Q)) with the VLC plugin, it shows the HTML markup of that object. Looking further into the HTML, you'll notice a `target="*"` tag. Open the URL inside this tag (in your case `IP:PORT/directory`) with the "Open Stream" option of VLC and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I found only one way to do that and that involves Firefox browser, DownloadHelper add-on, catching the stream address using DH add-on that is different than what you can get from the `target` attribute.

However, this catches about half a minute of a stream because in the meantime it changes its address. I don't know if that is because of the stream providers or something else.